# Mapping names in two files and getting a single file

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have two files, file A looks like this:

```
>MA0003.1_TFAP2A
5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
0.118921753043  0.383780891224  0.248648677866  0.248648677866
0.10270588744   0.308106851744  0.329728005881  0.259459254935
0.0486530020973 0.421617910964  0.427023199498  0.10270588744
>MA0004.1_Arnt
0.200009998 0.799890021996  4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05
0.949860027994  4.99900019996e-05   0.0500399920016 4.99900019996e-05
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994  4.99900019996e-05
>MA0006.1_Arnt::Ahr
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
 >MA0006.1_Arntr
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
 >MA0006.1_ArntAh
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
 4.16597233794e-05  0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
>MA0006.1_Arnt::A
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
```

and file B, that looks like this (please note that fileB also has spaces and the last word in each row is of importance):

```
AP-2    TFAP2A
AXUD class 1    Arnt
AXU 2   Arnt::Ahr
AXU  Arntr
AXU ArntAh
AXU Arnt::A
```

I want the third file that should be a combination of file A and B. Such that the name headers starting in file A should be adjusted, like this:

```
>AP-2
5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
0.118921753043  0.383780891224  0.248648677866  0.248648677866
0.10270588744   0.308106851744  0.329728005881  0.259459254935
0.0486530020973 0.421617910964  0.427023199498  0.10270588744
>AXUD class 1
0.200009998 0.799890021996  4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05
0.949860027994  4.99900019996e-05   0.0500399920016 4.99900019996e-05
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994  4.99900019996e-05
>Axu 2
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
```

`What I have done` is taken the file A and extracted the second name, which is seperated by underscore(_), like this:

```
awk '/>/' <input_for_clustering.pwm | tr '_' '\t' | awk '{print $2}' > temp
```

then checked the second file for the existence of these names in file B and extracting it, like this:

```
for i in `cat temp`
   do
         cat fileB | awk '{ if (($2=="'$i'")) {print $1 }}'>>data_res

       done
```

Now the thing is how to edit the file A?

kindly, help.

I hope, I showed the effort and the thought I had put in.

Comment: Do you know the name of the format these files are in? If so, there will almost certainly exist a parser that can do the editing for you.

Comment: The File B is in tab separated format.

Comment: I meant the other file.

Comment: The columns in FileA are separated by spaces.

Comment: `FileB` is surely in a standard format? It looks like bioinformatics to me.

Comment: You have updated the question to add more input but the output is the same as it was before. You should add the extra output to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{z=$NF;$NF="";a[z]=$0;next}
     /^>/{split($0,b,"_");if (b[2] in a){print ">"a[b[2]]}next}1' fileB fileA
```

Result:

```
>AP-2 
5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
0.118921753043  0.383780891224  0.248648677866  0.248648677866
0.10270588744   0.308106851744  0.329728005881  0.259459254935
0.0486530020973 0.421617910964  0.427023199498  0.10270588744
>AXUD class 1 
0.200009998 0.799890021996  4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05
0.949860027994  4.99900019996e-05   0.0500399920016 4.99900019996e-05
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994  4.99900019996e-05
>AXU 2 
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that file B also has spaces and only the last word is of concern.

Comment: As we use $NF it always use last word as key

Comment: Still working fine, check NF definition: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_101.html#SEC104

Comment: Hi please check the updates FileB and output in the question. It is slightly different now.

Comment: If you use the updated fileB, the desired output is not coming (please see the updated output also). As an example in second header it should be AXUD Class 1 and not only AXUD.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this does what you want:

```
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
NR==FNR { a[$2] = $1; next }
/^>/ { for (i in a) if ($0 ~ i "$") $0 = ">" a[i] }
{ print $0 }
```

When the total record number is equal to the record number of the current file (i.e. we are in the first file), build an array `a` containing the replacements. `next` skips the rest of the script and goes to the next line.

For lines in the second file starting with a ">", go through the keys of `a`, find the one that matches and make the replacement to the line. I've added an anchor `$` so the pattern must be at the end of the line. `{ print $0 }` prints the whole line (this can be abbreviated to simply `1`.

Testing it out:

```
$ awk -f swap.awk replace file
>AP-2
5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
0.118921753043  0.383780891224  0.248648677866  0.248648677866
0.10270588744   0.308106851744  0.329728005881  0.259459254935
0.0486530020973 0.421617910964  0.427023199498  0.10270588744
>AXUD class 1
0.200009998 0.799890021996  4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05
0.949860027994  4.99900019996e-05   0.0500399920016 4.99900019996e-05
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994  4.99900019996e-05
>AXU 2
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that file B also has spaces and only the last word is of concern. I am sorry, please check the edited output.

Comment: If the fields are separated by tabs, that's no problem. I've edited my answer so the Input Field Separator is set to the tab character.

Comment: Thank's. This is what I am doing, I saved your code as swao.awk and then executed as awk -f swap.awk fileB fileA. I get completely different output.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Are you sure? What exactly is different?

Comment: All the three header lines start with >AXU 2   Arnt::Ahr. No changes in names

Comment: I've made a minor edit to my code (I added a `"$"` to the pattern. Can you let me know if it works now?

Comment: Hi Tom, unfortunately, I still see the same output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl solution. It looks a little cryptic because it relies on a couple of regexes.

The strategy is to process `FileB` *first*, and build a hash that translates the strings in `FileA`.

All output is sent to STDOUT.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my %fb = do {
  open my ($fh), '<', 'FileB.txt';
  reverse map / ( \S+ (?: \s+ \S+ )* ) \s+ (\S+) /x, <$fh>;
};

open my ($fh), '<', 'FileA.txt';
while ( <$fh> ) {
   s/^>\K[^_]*_(\S+).*/$fb{$1}/;
   print;
}
```

**output**

```
>AP-2
5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
5.4052885343e-06    0.999983784134  5.4052885343e-06    5.4052885343e-06
0.118921753043  0.383780891224  0.248648677866  0.248648677866
0.10270588744   0.308106851744  0.329728005881  0.259459254935
0.0486530020973 0.421617910964  0.427023199498  0.10270588744
>AXUD class 1
0.200009998 0.799890021996  4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05
0.949860027994  4.99900019996e-05   0.0500399920016 4.99900019996e-05
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994
4.99900019996e-05   4.99900019996e-05   0.999850029994  4.99900019996e-05
>AXU 2
0.125020829862  0.333319446759  0.0833611064823 0.458298616897
4.16597233794e-05   4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   0.0417013831028
4.16597233794e-05   0.95821529745   4.16597233794e-05   0.0417013831028
```